# Fetching Data For crystal Report and displaying in it

Tags: c#, ms-access, crystal-reports

### Table1

DoctorID(Primary key),

Fee,

Fee-Unit,

Name

### Table2

DoctorID(Foreign Key),

Full Name,

Age

I have this two  Tables ,I am trying to fetch rows in which `DoctorID` is same(to display in `Crysatal report`) ,I tried below query and it is working fine and giving me result as shown in crystal report ,Now my problem is

1)In crystal report `Doctor name` is duplicating for number of patients (which I want to show only once )

2)same for Fee column fee is duplicating for `number of patients` time

3)below fee column I am showing its sum How do I give heading for this like "Total Fee="

4)And what if I don't want to show Patient Name only Count

Shall i use different datatables ? if so than what will b query for getting Number of Patients

**Query**

```
 da = new OleDbDataAdapter(@"SELECT d.[FirstName]&' '&d.[LastName] as [Doctor Name],d.[Fee_Unit], d.[Fee],p.[PFirstName]&' '&p.[PLastName] as [Patient Name],p.[Age],p.[BirthDate],p.[MobileNo]&' '&p.[LandlineNo] as [Contact Number] FROM Doctor_Master d,Patient_Registration p WHERE p.DoctorID=" + drId + " AND d.DoctorID=" + drId, acccon);
```

[image: Crystalreport]

Answer (score 0):

you should first make sum(fee) as totalFee, Count(PName) as total patient and grouped by seleted all field